# How to pass the extras to intent when the application gets launched using Alarm Manager?

Tags: android, android-intent

In the application which i'm developing, i'm having an alarm manager which will launch the application in particular time. During this process, i'm passing a string as the part of intents as shown below.

```
Intent LaunchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Application Package Name");
        String strName = "Preferences";
        LaunchIntent.putExtra("STRING_NAME", strName);
        context.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

It is opening the application. But in the when i do `intent.getStringExtra("STRING_NAME")`, in the onCreate() method of the Homescreen, the passed string value is not coming.

In this class i'm initializing the alarm manager for every 40 seconds as shown below in the onCreate method:

```
private static void SetScheduleSync(Context context) {
        Intent downloader = new Intent(context, ScheduleSyncManager.class);

        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1000, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 10000*4;
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, recurringDownload);
    }
```

Inside the ScheduleSyncManager.class, i have written code to open up the application by passing the extras as the pert of intent. When the application opens up, i checking whether is there any extra data in the particular intent.

Here is the ScheduleManagerDeclaration:

```
public class ScheduleSyncManager extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public Boolean IsCustomizingPresent = false;
    String strName = "Preferences";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Sync in the background has Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        performScheduleSync(context, intent);
    }

    public void performScheduleSync(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sap.rex.ui");
        launchIntent.putExtra("STRING_NAME", strName);
        launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(launchIntent);
        }
```

And i'm calling the ScheduleManager from function SetScheduleSync() in Oncreate() method as i posted the code below.

Please help me with this. Is it possible to do like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

P.S. It's a common practice to make the first letters of the instances lower case., i.e., not LaunchIntent but launchIntent.

Comment: sure i will try and let you know. Thank you

Comment: i have tired. But still it's not coming up as part of intent extras.

Comment: Maybe this: LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: no luck. Didn't worked. IS it possible to send like this??

Comment: If it's still not resolved, can you share your code so that we can also test it?

Comment: i have added the code. alarm manager setting i have done in onCreate() method and alarm manager is registered to ScheduleSyncManager.class which opens up the application. In this instance i'm passing the extras to intent.

Comment: Can you also pass how did you declare ScheduleSyncManager and where did you put your launchIntent in that class and also how did you call your intent in the MainActivity?

Comment: You have not added the last code I guess, i.e., calling intent in the MainActivity.

Comment: I'm calling this method SetScheduleSync() from MainActivity class, which sets the alarm manager. In this method i'm setting the intent.

Comment: I tried your code and the alarm did not work. First, make sure that the alarm works properly, maybe the problem is not the intent extra but the alarm itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've realised that I forgot to make changes in AndroidManifest file. Can you pass those changes, too.